How to share Saved State Handle to another view models?
I'm working on an Android application where I have a shared ViewModel that utilizes SavedStateHandle. I want to know if it's possible to create sub ViewModels in different screens (composables) using the same SavedStateHandle from the shared ViewModel.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
val sharedViewModel: MySharedViewModel = viewModel()

val subViewModel: MySubViewModel = viewModel(
    extras = // from shared view model creation extras?
)

Is there a way to pass the SavedStateHandle from the shared ViewModel to the sub ViewModels?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
